# Need a Javascript regex expression to match a language param in URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not familiar with regex and I haven't found any proper solution for my case.
My website utilizes such URLs:

```
(http(s)://www.)website.com/en/someURL
(http(s)://www.)website.com/anotherURL
(http(s)://www.)website.com/de/anotherURL
```

If `website.com/someURL`, `website.com/` or `website.com` is accessed the default language will be loaded.

I need a regex which will allow only these certain language codes, case sensitivity is not important:

```
(http(s)://www.)website.com/en
(http(s)://www.)website.com/en/
(http(s)://www.)website.com/
(http(s)://www.)website.com
(http(s)://www.)website.com/de
(http(s)://www.)website.com/de/
```

Comment: He needs a regex to parse language codes in an url... if there's no match, it will disallow certain codes from... ? To summarize, he doesn't know how to use regexes and wants the work done for him. @Kuzma I would recommend using https://regex101.com, javascript mode, and use the bottom right "quick reference" and play around with inputs and results.. of course after reading a tutorial on regexes.

Comment: Regex 101 is amazing. You can paste your test case into the bottom and pane and watch what gets matched as you fill in the regex. Play with it and come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47353219/edit) when you have something but you're stuck on something specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will work:

```
^((https?)?\:\/\/www\.)?website\.com(\/((de|en)\/?)?)?$
```

If you want to make some unit tests on [https://regex101.com/][1] you should erase the ^ and $ for beginning and end, otherwise you will see a positive result only if you use only one line.

For testing you could use this (if you want you can add some lines):

```
https://www.website.com/en
http://www.website.com/en/
https://www.website.com/
https://www.website.com
https://www.website.com/de
https://www.website.com/de/
```

Comment: Thank you! A little refinement: my framework doesn't need a check for this part `(http(s)://www.)website.com`. I've simplified your solution to `(((de|en)\/?)?)?` but in such way it doesn't match the root of website. In other words the `website.com/  and website.com` won't match. I need an additional rule to match null param and `/` at the end of website's address.

Comment: I put a questionmark behind the ^((https?)?\:\/\/www\.) so the first part is optional and the website.com/ and website.com will match.

Answer (score 2):

you only have to limit the number of letters to two and with that you get the language `\w{2}`

```
https?\:\/\/www\.website\.com\/((\w{2})\/?$|(\w{2})\/)
```

e.g. https://regex101.com/r/SCbDyY/2

Comment: only one little issue with this, it doesn't match: `website.com/ and website.com`

Comment: @Kuzma `.com(\/((\w{2})\/?$|(\w{2})\/)?)?` :)